# How to update database using adapters in mobilefirst 7.1

Tags: sql, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am able to successfully create adapter for creation and insertion in sql but updation i have doubt below is my code where i want to update a certain field values based on wrkname and i am getting in or out error.

```
var updateStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("UPDATE office1 SET wrkid=?, wrkname=?, empref=? WHERE wrkname=?");

function updateoffice(wrkid,wrkname,empref,wrkname) {

    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : updateStatement,
        parameters : [wrkid,wrkname,empref,wrkname]
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Provide the full error message.

Comment: "Runtime: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 4.\nPerformed query:\nUPDATE office1 SET wrkid=?, wrkname=?, empref=? WHERE wrkname=?"

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the fourth parameter, wrkname (which you're using twice...)?

For example, this worked well for me:

```
var update = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("UPDATE users SET stdid=? WHERE userId=?");
function updatevaluesprocedure(stdId,userId) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : update,
       parameters : [stdId,userId]
    });
}
```

Two parameters are expected, two parameters were received.

In your case four parameters are expected...

Comment: thank you i have updated and am getting new error "I O: expecting either ',' or ']' on line 1, column 42".

Comment: but my program logic is i have 3 columns (wrkid,wrkname,empref) and row of data ("1","fxxx","fx@yahoo.co") and based on wrkname="fxxx" i need to change the complete row.is this possible .if any solution pls

Comment: I am saying, you don't need to send it twice!! updateoffice(wrkid,wrkname,empref,wrkname) - remove the last wrkname, as it is the same as the first.

Comment: but where clause values ??? if i didnt mention it will replace all the rows right ???

Comment: Dude. I am only saying to remove it from the function signature. I am not saying to remove it from the list of parameters or from the SQL query.

Comment: sorry i am not getting it can u provide some samples for updation or can u modify the above code .based on the wrk name i need to modify all fields(wrkid,wrkname,empref) how to do this